# How to get data by max(date) group by column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In the table below I need `lastservice` data based on the last date group by nopol.

Table data:

[image]

I tried to use the query below

```
SELECT 
    TGL, A.NOPOL, LASTSERVICE 
FROM 
    TRREALPRWT AS A
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         MAX(TGLREAL) AS TGL, NOPOL 
     FROM 
         TRREALPRWT 
     GROUP BY 
         NOPOL) AS B ON B.NOPOL = A.NOPOL
GROUP BY 
    A.NOPOL, TGL,LASTSERVICE
```

but the results obtained are not per nopol.

What I should do from the query so that it produces data like the following

```
| NOPOL   | LASTSERVICE | TGLREAL                   |
| L9235VB | 224270      | 2018-01-26 00: 00: 00.000 |
| B9891JT | 219270      | 2018-02-28 00: 00: 00.000 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take all `MAX(TGL)` for all `NOPOL` in an inner query and join it again with your original table matching on `NOPOL` and `MAX(TGL)` values.

```
SELECT T.NOPOL, T.TGL, T.LASTSERVICE
FROM
YOUR_TABLE T
INNER JOIN
(SELECT NOPOL, MAX(TGL) AS MAX_TGL FROM YOUR_TABLE GROUP BY NOPOL) A
ON T.NOPOL = A.NOPOL AND T.TGL = A.MAX_TGL;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work, assuming TGLREAL is your date.

```
SELECT TGL,A.NOPOL,LASTSERVICE FROM TRREALPRWT
WHERE TGLREAL IN (SELECT MAX(TGLREAL) FROM  TRREALPRWT)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is seems to be use only `group by` clause no need to inner query

```
select nopol, min(LASTSERVICE) LASTSERVICE, max(TGL) TGLREAL  
from TRREALPRWT 
group by nopol
```

Answer (score 0):

The sample output in the question seems to indicate that you want the first tgl for each nopol, max(lastservice)

```
SELECT nopol,MIN(lastservice) lastservice,  MAX(tgl) tglreal
FROM trreal
GROUP BY nopol
```